# Как в списке произвольной длины заменить каждый второй символ на символ 0 при помощи среза в Python?

Tags: python

Имеется список `a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`. Количество элементов в списке произвольное. Необходимо заменить каждый второй элемент списка на символ `0` используя срез. В результате должно получиться `[1,0,3,0,5,0,7,0,9,0]`. Пробовал вот так:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = len(a)
c = b / 2
a[::2] = [0] * c
print(a)
[0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 10] #но ответ вышел таким
```

Comment: Кстати, в Python 3 работать вообще не будет, надо делить нацело `c = b // 2`

Comment: Да, точно. Проглядел. Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему ответ вышел таким? Потому что не с того индекса начался срез

```
a[1::2]
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. Только вот одно не совсем понятно: везде пишут, что у среза три параметра [<начало>:<конец>:<шаг>] А тут a[1:: 2] как бы четыре получается. В чем тут подвох? Можете объяснить начинающему, т.е. мне? Или ссылкой поделиться.  Спасибо и благодарю.

Comment: @Rich Тут два параметра же указано. Может быть ещё один между ::, т.е. максимум 3 параметра: `[1:2:3]`

Comment: Спасибо большое вам. Ах вот оно как! А я думал что двоеточие это по умолчанию и есть параметр если первое двоеточие - значит 0 элемент, если второе двоеточие - значит конец списка, ну а третье двоеточие - значит каждый элемент (т.е  не пропускаем с каким-то шагом). Поглядел я на код и стало понятно, что просто надо было сместить на один элемент. "Вот же дуб" - подумал я про себя). А вообще как вам мой код? Правильный ли ход мысли? Можно ли его записать более коротко. Успехов и счастья.

Comment: Лишние переменные только убрать `a[1::2] = [0]*(len(a)//2)`